# Unable to boot into ubuntu after windows update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I used to have a dual boot option on my pc until the latest update of windows. The two boot options were: Windows 10 and ubuntu MATE. After the windows update No.1703 I am unable to boot into ubuntu.

Below you can find a link coming from boot-repair where it seems like the ubuntu partition(sda4) is not recognised.

Link to boot-repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25708669/

Does anyone have the same problem and can provide a solution?

Regards.